# Unable to uninstall PostgreSQL 9.3 from Ubuntu 14.04 without installing PostgreSQL 10

Tags: 14.04, apt, postgresql

I just upgraded my Postgres instance from 9.3 to 9.6, and everything worked perfectly until I tried to uninstall 9.3. Apt is trying to install Postgres 10 during the removal of 9.3. 9.6 needs to stay where it is. It's not the end of the world if I don't remove 9.3, but I'd love to clean house a bit.

`sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3` returns this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  comerr-dev krb5-multidev libgssrpc4 libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9
  libkdb5-7 libossp-uuid16
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-contrib
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc locales-all postgresql-doc-10
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-10 postgresql-client-10
The following packages will be upgraded:
  postgresql postgresql-contrib
2 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 216 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,318 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I haven't found a way to remove postgresql-9.3 without installing postgresql-10. Thanks in advance, and I hope this is a simple matter of not knowing the proper Apt command.

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3 postgresql-10`? Or just `sudo apt-get remove postgresql`?

Comment: The first suggestion seems to work, although I don't know exactly why. `The following packages will be REMOVED: postgresql postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib postgresql-contrib-9.3` It seems sketchy that it wants to remove postgresql, though.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if I'm double dipping somehow. I went back and read the instructions I used for the upgrade. Here's part of the instructions I used from Postgresql's site. "Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository: `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`"

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the uninstall script inside postgress folder.

In my case:

`sudo chmod +x /opt/PostgreSQL/version_here/uninstall-postgresql
 sudo ./opt/PostgreSQL/version_here/uninstall-postgresql`